# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{nx}}{n^p}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Using the $p-$ test $\Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$ is convergent for $p>1$.

Using the comparison test $\Rightarrow$ $$a_n=\frac{\cos{nx}}{n^p},b_n=\frac{1}{n^p}$$

then $a_n$ is convergent if $p>1$ and divergent if $p\le 1$.

Is this the only necessary condition for convergence of $a_n$?

Comment: Do you know anything about $x$?

Comment: You can't use comparison test for sequences which aren't everywhere positive, so this doesn't work for $x$ not a multiple of $\pi$. Dirichlet test might be of help here.

Comment: @Hirshy  $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Then you should follow @Wojowu hint, as you don't neccesarily have strict positive $a_n$.

Comment: Notice that when $p>1$, you can show that the series converges absolutely using the Comparison Test.

Comment: If $x=\pi$, for $p=1$ we have the series $-1+1/2-1/3+1/4-1/5+\dotsb$; this is convergent, so your claim about divergence when $p\le1$ is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{\cos nx}{n^p} \right| \leq  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p},
$$
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos nx}{n^p} $ is absolutely convergent for $p>1$, and hence convergent for $p>1.$